Does boost asio guarantee a handler callback when async operation is pending?
To handle timeouts, let's assume I set up a steady_timer to go off right before async_resolve, async_connect, async_write, async_read_some...
When the timer fires, I shutdown & close the socket. Also, resolver.cancel().
Can I expect appropriate handler callback with an error if ANY async op is pending? Is callback guaranteed?

Yes, the handler will be called

@AlanBirtles unless the process is terminated or the service is stopped (and not resumed)
